# Получить значение select и вставить в id

Tags: jquery

Есть html код

```
<select id="select">
    <option aria-label="22" value="10000" selected="">м3</option>
    <option value="455">шт</option>
  </select>
```

как мне вставить значение aria-label в id="show_selected"

```
<input id="show_selected" class="amount_input cart-count-val" value="1" type="text">
```

ниже скрипт не работает

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('body').on('change','#select', function() {
         $('#show_selected').attr('option[aria-label]');
    });
});
```

Comment: Зачем? Что-то мне подсказывает, что ваша задача решается по-другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала получить атрибут, а потом присвоить его значение инпуту. Вы же пытаетесь просто получить атрибут ИНПУТА

Должно быть примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('body').on('change','#select', function() {
        var attr = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('aria-label');
         $('#show_selected').val(attr);
    });
});
```